# Fetching A single row from SQLite DB and saving the values into individual variable and displaying them into different text views

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am running a Query in my DB Adapter class something like this where in I provide an ID and want to fetch the row associated with that ID:

```
    public Cursor fetchRow(String a) {
    String Key = a; 

    return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE0, new String[] {IDno1, GIDno1,Name1,Owner1,Breed1,Gender1}, "IDno=?",new String[]{Key}, null, null, null, null);
}
```

Now in my Class I want to bind the individual elements returned from this Query to different variables, but I am confused how to achieve that. I am doing something like:

```
    private void fillData() {
    Cursor c = DBHelper.fetchRow();

   // List<String> idList = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {


             }
}
```

Comment: read a minimum documentation (like, Cursor class documentation, android developer storage guide ...), try a few things, encounter an actual issue, ask a real question

Comment: I have done a Cursor to list View but not able to understand what I do here!

Comment: If my answer helped you. Kindly accept it as answer so other can get benefited in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try {
            c = null;
            String select = "Select * FROM tbl";
            c = db.rawQuery(select, null);
            if (null!=c) {
                while (c.moveToNext()) {
                    //Here you can directly set the value in textview
                    txtview.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("column_name")));
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            c.close();
        }
```

This way you can get your values and set it to the textview directly. If you are sure that you have only one row than don't use while statement.

```
if (null!=c) {
    c.moveToNext();
    txtview.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("column_name")));
}
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

do something like this
make a class in which declare setter and getter

```
 private void fillData() {
    Cursor c = DBHelper.fetchRow();

    List<String> idList = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            IdList q = new IdList ();
            q.setid0(c.getString(0));
            q.setid1(c.getString(1));
            q.setid2(c.getString(2));
            q.setid3(c.getString(3));
            q.setid4(c.getString(4));
                idList .add(q);
            }
        } while (c.moveToNext());


    }
}
```

and get the value from the class and set into textview

Comment: And how do I set the values from the List to text views?

Answer (score 0):

You need something like:

```
variable1 = c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("Column1"));
variable2 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Column2"));
```